# Cannot make a GET request in Postman with React

Tags: reactjs, postman

I created a joke generator app that takes jokes from a local json file with data that I created and displays it in the browser. This app has no backend at all. I am trying to make a GET request through Postman, but no luck. Is it even possible to use postman in this scenario?

Comment: no postman is to test an api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO Postman is not used for programmatic api calls. Use axios for this. Suppose your server is running on localhost:3000.

```
npm install axios
```

In your component,

```
    const axios = require('axios');
    // Make a request for a user with a given ID
    axios.get('/jokes?id=1')
      .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
        // always executed
      });
```